# taking the gradient in Tensorflow, tf.gradient

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, partial, derivative

I am using this function of tensorflow to get my function jacobian. Came across two problems:

1. The tensorflow documentation is contradicted to itself in the following two paragraph if I am not mistaken:

> gradients() adds ops to the graph to output the partial derivatives of ys with respect to xs. It returns a list of Tensor of length len(xs) where each tensor is the sum(dy/dx) for y in ys.
>   Blockquote
>
> Blockquote
>   Returns:
>   A list of sum(dy/dx) for each x in xs.
>   Blockquote

According to my test, it is, in fact, return a vector of len(ys) which is the sum(dy/dx) for each x in xs.

2. I do not understand why they designed it in a way that the return is the sum of the columns(or row, depending on how you define your Jacobian).
3. How can I really get the Jacobian?

4.In the loss, I need the partial derivative of my function with respect to input (x), but when I am optimizing with respect to the network weights, I define x as a placeholder whose value is fed later, and weights are variable, in this case, can I still define the symbolic derivative of function with respect to input (x)? and put it in the loss? ( which later when we optimize with respect to weights will bring second order derivative of the function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you are right and there is a typo there, it was probably meant to be "of length len(ys)".
2. For efficiency. I can't explain exactly the reasoning, but this seems to be a pretty fundamental characteristic of how TensorFlow handles automatic differentiation. See [issue #675](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675).
3. There is no straightforward way to get the Jacobian matrix in TensorFlow. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347275/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-gradients-and-tf-train-optimizer-compute-gradi/45347628#45347628) and again [issue #675](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675). Basically, you need one call to `tf.gradients` per column/row.
4. Yes, of course. You can compute whatever gradients you want, there is no real difference between a placeholder and any other operation really. There are a few operations that do not have a gradient because it is not well defined or not implemented (in which case it will generally return 0), but that's all.